# Formally undecidable problems on finitely presented quandles

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, logic

In the literature, one sometimes sees the claim that finitely presented quandles (in particular, knot quandles) are "hard to deal with".  Hence, a great deal of effort has gone into studying finite quandles and counting homomorphisms onto them, and so on.  However, I have not yet come across any theorems that state formal undecidability results for finitely presented quandles similar to those for finitely presented groups.  In fact, I have yet to see any formulation of such problems.  (For instance, a theorem stating that the isomorphism problem is undecidable for finitely presented quandles.)

Do such results exist in the literature and, if so, could someone please provide references?

EDIT: (Asked same question on [Math Overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/74162/formally-undecidable-problems-on-finitely-presented-quandles))